# Configure error while installing R-3.4.1 from source without root access

Tags: r, curl

I am trying to install R-3.4.1 and got the following error:

```
checking for curl-config... /home/menglan.xiang/usr/bin/curl-config
checking libcurl version ... 7.55.1
checking curl/curl.h usability... yes
checking curl/curl.h presence... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.22.0... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.22.0 library and headers are required with support for https
configure: WARNING: cache variable ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value contains a newline
```

Tried almost every solution on Stack Overflow and nothing works. curl was installed successfully with openssl enabled. Here is the configure command:

```
export CPPFLAGS='-I/$HOME/usr/include/curl'
export LDFLAGS='-L/$HOME/usr/lib/'
./configure --prefix=$HOME --with-x=no
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/$HOME/usr/include/
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/$HOME/usr/lib/
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/$HOME/usr/lib/pkgconfig/
```

And if your `curl-config` is not detected correctly, also add this:

```
$ export PATH=$HOME/usr/bin:$PATH
```

---

**For the record**

On my multiarch Ubuntu machine, where I had a leftover `libcurl` in `/usr/local/`, it actually required me to do this:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib
$ export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```